# Making a .exe in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Could anyone be kind, and tell me how to make a exe file in visual studio 2008 for a win32 console based, c++ program? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the Win32 Console Application type in the New C++ wizard. Building this will produce a native C++ executable application.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb7sxUNuFe4

Comment: n.b. the first link is a fully spoonfed video tutorial with VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

See [msdn visual studio tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384842.aspx)